Changes aren't being applied as I refresh the localhost page. Any idea why it might be?
I'm working on a college project, where the group decided to use xampp, and apparentely, this is happening to every member.
I open up xampp and turn on Apache server, I just get onto visual studio and start coding, because we are at frontend basically for this first sprint, but the thing is, the changes I'm making to the css file aren't being applied as it was usual (literally used to make a change, refresh, look at the preview...), and now it works like this: I change something in css, wait 2 work days, and it changes.
At first I thought I was editing the wrong file, so I just trashed it and cloned it back from GitHub, but it didn't solve anything.
Plus, I'm pretty sure it wasn't the problem once when I woke up today, the small changes that I made yesterday were applied.
I'm really confused, this might be actually pretty simple, the thing is I'm pretty new to xampp and Php, I don't know if I'm missing something.

Changes to CSS files won't reload the dev server by default. What bundler are you using, webpack? If so, follow this guide

I'm in my first year, I don't even know what a bundler is, I don' know if it's because of the language barrier, or actual lack of knowledge, can you elaborate, please?

I have had this issue too, for me, it helped to switch browser normally I use opera, but it didn't change my CSS changes but on Google it did.
Hope this helps

Actually worked. I was using Edge, never gave me this kinda problem so far. But chrome seems to be working perfectly fine tho.
Thank you very much.
